# Robotium waitForFragment

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

Is there an equivalent method for fragments just like there is for activities?

I have an app and want to test fragment transactions.

Any other workarounds? I hate to put solo.sleep(2000) just to wait for the transaction to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 3.3 of Robotium added waitForFragment() methods.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know from which version on but now (3.6) Robotium has 4 methods work with fragment

waitForFragmentById(int) - Method in class com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
Waits for a Fragment with a given id to appear.

waitForFragmentById(int, int) - Method in class com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
Waits for a Fragment with a given id to appear.

waitForFragmentByTag(String) - Method in class com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
Waits for a Fragment with a given tag to appear.

waitForFragmentByTag(String, int) - Method in class com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
Waits for a Fragment with a given tag to appear.

Check the javadoc to find out details.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any text that you can "wait" for using `waitForText()`? There is also a `waitForView()` method.

Not sure if any of that will help, but figured it was worth a shot.